# Pandas DataFrame: convert WKT into GeoJSON in a new column using Lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, geojson, wkt

I have some data in this format:

```
Dep       Dest        geom
----      ----        -----
EDDF      KIAD        LINESTRING(3.961389 43.583333, 3.968056 43.580....
```

Which contains flight trajectories. The geom column contains the coordinates in WKT format. It is possible to convert them via the library [geomet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geomet/0.1.0) to GeoJSON format, which I want to do in a new column.

In order to do this efficiently with Pandas, I am trying to do:

```
from geomet import wkt
import json

df = .... #load data to df
df['geojson'] =  df['geom'].apply(lambda x: json.dumps(wkt.loads(x['geom'] )))
```

Which does not work. Any way to make it happen?

Comment: The rror it gives me is "string indices must be integers".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the following line:

```
df['geojson'] =  df['geom'].apply(lambda x: json.dumps(wkt.loads(x['geom'] )))
```

into this one:

```
df['geojson'] =  df['geom'].apply(lambda x: json.dumps(wkt.loads(x)))
```

This produce the desired results:

```
from geomet import wkt
import json

#Generate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"Dep":["EDDf"],
                   "Dest": ["KIAD"],
                   "geom": ["LINESTRING(3.961389 43.583333, 3.968056 43.580)"]})


#Apply function to create new column
df["geojson"] = df["geom"].apply(lambda x: json.dumps(wkt.loads(x)))
```

This creates:

```
    Dep  Dest                                             geom                                            geojson
0  EDDf  KIAD  LINESTRING(3.961389 43.583333, 3.968056 43.580)  {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[3.9613...
```

Comment: Hello Marjan, thanks, now I get KeyError: ('geom', 'occurred at index dep')